# Battletech Sensor warfare

Tags: battletech

While playing [*BattleTech*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BattleTech_(video_game)) (2018) by Harebrained Schemes, the refit screen has a tutorial button that mentions stealth options, and using probes. I'm assuming these are somewhat similar to the Guardian ECM suite and Beagle probe I encountered playing [*MechCommander*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MechCommander).

However, I've not seen any items of this type in *Battletech* so far (either stores, black market or salvage).

As these have the potential to make the gameplay quite different (currently it's basically like tower defence) I'd be interested to know more about them.

I've seen them referenced in relation to the [*Urban Warfare*](https://www.strategygamer.com/articles/battletech-urban-warfare-expansion/) update, but just wondering if they are only available with the DLC, and/or if they appear in the main campaign at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember them in the main game, so without a mod, I think the Urban Warfare DLC is your only option.

There is a free mod that will help you out with having to buy DLC called Roguetech.  The "downside" is that it is a super-comprehensive makeover to the game but it definitely includes your sought-after sensors, ECM, ECCM, and visual stealth components.  It's also got all (or at least almost all) the other toys they've ever dreamed up for Battletech such as mechs (including a ton of variants), vehicles, weapons, melee components, and probably more stuff that I am forgetting.  Frankly, I'm not sure I could ever go back to vanilla Battletech after playing Roguetech.

If this sounds interesting to you, the best place to check out is the Roguetech wiki (https://roguetech.gamepedia.com/Roguetech_Wiki).  On the right side is an installation guide that should help you get started.

Comment: Yes the Roguetech mod does look fascinating, and I do plan on installing it once I finished my play through of vanilla. I've bought the DLC's now (season pass) though, so they should appear somewhere (in the sandbox, if not the story campaign).

Answer (score -3):

I had the tabletop Battletech way back in the day, so I'm not sure what version it was. It had a Warhammer on the cover and plastic figures inside. 
Anyway, I've been away for quite some time, so please bear with me. 
As I recall, the point of the Beagle Active Probe was to "sniff out" mechs that were shut down. Normal sensors were supposed to be incapable of sensing a shut down mech. The BAP would allow you to know they were there. The ECm suite would mess with lock ons and such. Now it's my understanding that the stealth technology is just what it says; it is trying to prevent detection, but the ECM and BAP can possibly counter this.

Here are some links that may help:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Battletechgame/comments/bwdjlw/stealth_mech_battletech_urban_warfare_dlc/

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj7pv_12LflAhWBjFkKHRNTAFwQFjADegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sarna.net%2Fwiki%2FStealth&usg=AOvVaw00VZ8veVPuo91CPOBmLvkZ

Comment: The question is talking about the video game, but most of your original text is about the tabletop wargame. This is effectively a link-only answer. Stack Exchange is different from forums you may be used to - each answer is supposed to stand on it's own. Link-only answers are unacceptable because the links may go bad, and then the answer carries no meaning at all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I'm used to Quora where everything needs a citation to be valid. That being said, In MechWarrior 3 for PC, I have used BAP to find shut down mechs and see the other enemies farther out. It also provided more details. I have never used or encountered stealth armor.

Comment: Citations are very important. My point was that the bulk of the original text has nothing to do with the video game. The only parts that seem to relate to the video game are links. This would be a valid answer if you trimmed back the table top game stuff and actually included relevant portions of the linked pages in the answer. That way, if the links go stale, the answer is still useful.